# Unexpected result when using RF pulsed generator in ADS

Tags: rf, pulse, transient, ads

I am simulating a simple test circuit including an RFpulsed generator in ADS, but the simulation gived some surprising result.

I have attached my test circuit schematic in the attachment. Moreover, I have added the simulation plot there. Pay attention to the output resistor value of the RFpulsed generator. I have a couple of questions:

1- The output voltage value of the RFpulsed generator probe (Vin) is not correct as per its output resistor. What do you think?

2- I have applied a time delay of 50 μs at the beginning of PulseRF. moreover, the start time of simulation is 0 s; the stop time of simulation was set at 100 ns. So, nothing should have been shown in the simulation result. What do you think about this?

3- When I want to do a transient simulation without the DC supply, while I have the RFpulsed generator, I encounter a message preventing simulation. What do you think the reason could be?

[image]

Comment: For question 3, please include the full text of the error message.

Comment: Hi @ThePhoton
in fact, this is not an error. but this prevent simulation. the message is in the following:
"no source was found. place one from the component palette, wire it up, and resimulate."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the PulseRF source, but based on your observations and reading the documentation, I believe that it is only active in Ptolemy simulations, not in transient simulations.

First, in the [documentation for the PulseRF source](https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/display/ads2009/PulseRF), we see that it is part of the "TSDF" library:

[image]

Then, in the documentation page for [Theory of Operation for ADS Ptolemy Simulation](https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/display/ads2009/Theory+of+Operation+for+ADS+Ptolemy+Simulation) we see that Transient and Timed Synchronous Dataflow (TSDF) are considered entirely separate domains of simulation:

[image]

From this I believe that you can't expect the PulseRF source to act as a source in a transient simulation any more than you would expect an AC source (active only in AC simulations) or S-parameter port source (active only in S-parameter simulations) to do so.

To simulate this type of source in a transient simulation, you can construct a similar transient source by, for example multiplying the output of a sinusoidal source with an offset square wave source.

Comment: Thank you so much @The Photon 
I just want to know why this does not work without a source. in my original project, I have some other sources and therefore I can do the simulation. anyway, as per you said before, maybe I need to define other pulse RF source to do the transient simulation.